# Which of the following Lewis Structures is NOT correct?

Tags: lewis-structure

Which of the following Lewis Structures is NOT correct?

[image]

Comment: [Homework policy](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange). This site does not exist to do your homework. However, if there is any *specific* concept that you are struggling with, we would be glad to help you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no effort has been shown towards solving this question from an assignment.

Answer (score 1):

The first one, Fluorine does not have a full octet, is electron deficient and would have a charge. Also, the Nitrogen has too many electrons in its valence. And by the way, this is not a site to post homework questions.